# Unterschied zwischen Kindergarten und Kita

Tags: meaning

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen Kindertagesstätte und Kindergarten? Ist das eine Wort ein Oberbegriff oder handelt es sich um zwei verschiedene Einrichtungen?

Comment: WIkipedia erklärt es ganz gut: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindertagesstätte Der wichtigste hinweis dort: _Die genaue Definition ist national oder regional unterschiedlich._ Für mich ist der Unterschied die Dauer der Betreueung. Eine Kita bietet eine Ganztagesbetreuung an, d.h. mit Mittagessen. Ein Kindergarten bietet Vor- und manchmal Nachmittagsbetreung an. Zum Essen müssen die Kinder nach Hause.

Comment: @knut Welche Region ist das? Ich kenne Kindergarten nur mit Mittagessen und Ende zwischen 15 und 18 Uhr je nach Einrichtung. (Sachsen und Oberbayern)

Comment: (1/2) Ich hörte von der Unterscheidung zwischen Kita und Kindergarten basierend auf der Betreuungsdauer ebenso, allerdings nur in Nachrichtensendungen im Fernsehen und in Zeitungen. Auch Erwähnenswert ist der Begriff Ganztageskindergarten, der mir als ein geläufiger Begriff erscheint (NRW) auch wenn er wohl langsam verdrängt wird durch Kindertagesstätte.

Comment: (2/2) Ich vermute das Kita einfach nur Neusprech von Leuten ist die Kindergarten wie z.B. Obstgarten und nicht wie z.B. Lustgarten interpretieren (Wie kannst du es Kindergarten nennen? Es sind doch keine Tulpen! Wir sprechen über Menschen!!!!111elf). Ich werde weiterhin Kindergarten sagen und wenn nötig mit Ganztageskindergarten spezifizieren. Kita klingt auch ehr wie etwas das ein Baby von sich geben würde den etwas das ein Erwachsener sagen würde...

Comment: @Matthias BAden-Württembrg, Mittlerer Neckar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Begriffsbestimmung via Google

#### Kịn·der·gar·ten

`Substantiv [der]
    Institution zur Betreuung für Kinder im Vorschulalter, wo diese spielen 
    können und gefördert werden.`

#### Kịn·der·ta·ges·stät·te

`Substantiv [die]
    Kindergarten oder Kinderhort, in dem die Kinder den ganzen Tag betreut 
    werden.`

Also ersteres ist nahe liegend.

Comment: Zumindest im Kindergarten meiner Kinder ist "Vorschulalter" nur der Begriff für das letztze Jahr vor der Einschulung. Die Kinder sind aber i.d.R. 3 Jahre dort, ab dem 3. Geburtstag bzw. dem September danach. Und Kita wird in meinem Umfeld auch für Krippen verwendet sowie für Einrichtungen, die Kinder von < 3 Jahren bis zur Schule betreuuen.